# C# LINQ Entity Framework query that ignores nulls as part of the search

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model from which I am trying to create LINQ query. The model contains multiple properties, some of which can be null.

I would like to create build a LINQ statement that does not attempt to search on the null or empty valued properties.

Example:

```
public class MySearch
{
   public string Prop1 { get; set; }
   public decimal? Prop2 { get; set; }
   public int? Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

I want a single LINQ statement that ignores a property when it's null.

Something like:

```
var searchResults = myContext.MyStuff
            .Where(

   //If Prop1 is not null, but Prop2 and Prop3 ARE null, only query on Prop1
   //If Prop1 and Prop2 are not null, but Prop3 is null, query on Prop1 and Prop2
   //If Prop2 and Prop3 are not null, but Prop1 is null, query on Prop2 and Prop3
   //etc.

            );
```

Comment: You *don't* need that at all. There's no need for catch-all properties in LINQ, where you can construct your query at runtime. Just make different `.Where()` calls eg. `if (x){ query=query.Where(def=>def.prop=>mySearch.Prop1);}`

Comment: You can combine multiple different `Where` calls the same way

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis, I'm not sure if I understand your response. I trying to avoid making multiple Where statements.I have 8 properties some or all of which could have values, and I am trying to avoid a Where statement for each combination.

Comment: Why? Why would that be a problem? The generated SQL would be *better* than the [catch-all parameters](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) you want to use. With LINQ you can generate just the query you really need, taking advantage of appropriate execution plans. Catch-all queries in SQL result in *bad* plans half the time

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Maybe they want it the other way around: `.Where(x => x.Prop1 == mySearch.Prop1 || x.Prop1 == null)`. But the question is very unclear.

Comment: @ABogus You better post code that works and (almost) does what you want, but needs improvement, instead of pseudo code which leaves much room to speculation.

Comment: Sorry Gert Arnold, I just modified the question which is now mostly pseudo code. I don't know what other way to ask the question.

Comment: @GertArnold the original code  was a clear catch-all. The current one still describes a catch-all. There are only 3 different cases though, so a switch would be enough to pick a proper `Where()` clause, probably using pattern matching to make it prettier

Comment: Thanks everyone. I was misreading the solution by zaitsman, but it did work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have pointed out, just change your code like so:

```
var searchResults = myContext.MyStuff;

if (Prop1 != null)
{
    searchResults = searchResults.Where(def => def.prop == mySearch.Prop1);
}     

if (Prop2 != null)
{
    searchResults = searchResults.Where(def => def.prop == mySearch.Prop2);
}     

if (Prop3 != null)
{
    searchResults = searchResults.Where(def => def.prop == mySearch.Prop3);
}     

// At this point the query has not executed yet.

return searchResults.ToArray(); // here, the query has run.
```

Comment: This solved my issue. One note, I declared searchResults as IQueryable<EntityName>